# python - pass argument to function in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement, function-calls

I've something like a switch, that given an option will call a function e.g.

```
#... capture option
op = getOption()
#.. capture metric
mt = getMetric()

def zipcode():
    print "You typed zero.\n"
def desc():
    print "n is a perfect square\n"
def address():
    print "n is an even number\n"

#call desired option
options= {0 : zipcode,
          1 : code,
          2 : desc,
          3 : address
}

options[op]()
```

I am trying to pass a parameter (**mt**) into my **options** dict that will call a function, but i'm not being able to do so.

if op received is 1 and mt is foo, how the call to  the right function (zipcode) will be done by passing mt as a parameter?

ideally: `options[op](mt)` and defining one parameter in the function?

Thanks

Comment: "ideally: options[op](mt) and defining one parameter in the function?" Well, yes. Given that you know the answer I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: my bad, I was also specifying the parameter in the dictionary like: `options= {0 : zipcode(param1), ..`. I'm still learning this awesome python tricks! thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not indented properly, which is very important in Python and would cause syntax errors as is.

However, what you are suggesting would work perfectly.

Consider the following:

```
def multiply(m,n):
    return n*n

def add(m,n)
    return m,n

my_math = { "+":add,
            "*":multiply}
```

You could then call that as follows:

```
>>> print my_math["+"](1,2)
3
>>> print my_math["*"](4,5)
20
```

Comment: Ha, got it! I was specifying a parameter in the dictionary function like`options= {0 : zipcode(param1),  .. ` still did not quiet understand how these pythonic calls it works, but it rocks :)

Comment: code is now indented, just wrote a small example and miss the last breaked with right indentation.